# A problem of python plot for large number of data

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I am new to python and trying to plot a color magnitude diagram(CMD) for a selected cluster by matplotlib, there are 3400000 stars that I need to plot, the data for each star would be color on x axis and magnitude on y axis, However, my code should read two columns in a csv file and plot. The problem is when I using a part of the data (3000 stars), I can plot a CMD succesfully but when I use all the data, the plot is very mess(see figure below) and it seems that points are ploted by their positions in the column instead of its value. For example, a point has data (0.92,20.64) should be close to the y-axis, but is actually located at the far right of the plot just becasue it placed at last few columns of the dataset. So I wanna know how can I plot the entire dataset and show a plot like the first figure.Thanks for yout time. These are my codes:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Peter\Desktop\F275W test.csv', low_memory=False)

# Generate some test data
x = data['F275W-F336W']
y = data['F275W']

#remove the axis
plt.axis('off')
plt.plot(x,y, ',')
plt.show()
```

[This is the plot I got for 3000 stars it's a CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO26q.jpg)
[This is the plot I got for entire dataset, which is very mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIS0V.png)

Comment: Don't plot all your data. But do some analysis on them and get some representative data (smaller size) for visualization.

Comment: For example, select and plot only the stars with magnitude > 7.

Comment: Sample from your data representaviley, and only plot sample.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I think I need to plot not all of them but most of them, I will try to set a certain range for star s that i want to plot, but do you know what caused this weird bug?